# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 when compiling c++ and assembly code on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, assembly, apple-m1, arm64

I am reading this book an ARM64 assembly and there is a chapter where you have to call assembly code from c++.

every time I compile it I get this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_IntegerAddSubA_", referenced from:
      _main in main-11e536.o
  "_IntegerAddSubB_", referenced from:
      _main in main-11e536.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int IntegerAddSubA_(int a, int b, int c);
extern "C" long IntegerAddSubB_(long a, long b, long c);

template <typename T>
void PrintResult(const char* msg, T a, T b, T c, T result){
    const char nl = '\n';
    
    cout << msg << nl;
    cout << "a" << a << nl;
    cout << "b" << b << nl;
    cout << "c" << c << nl;
    cout << "result (a + b + c) = " << result << nl;
    cout << nl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a1 = 100, b1 = 200, c1 = -50, result1;
    result1 = IntegerAddSubA_(a1, b1, c1);
    PrintResult("IntergerAddSubA_", a1, b1, c1, result1);
    
    long a2 = 1000, b2 = -2000, c2 = 500, result2;
    result2 = IntegerAddSubB_(a2, b2, c2);
    PrintResult("IntegerAddSubB_", a2, b2, c2, result2);
    return 0;
}
```

**ch.S**

```
    .text
    .global IntegerAddSubA_
    .align 2

IntegerAddSubA_:
    add W3,W0,W1
    sub W0,W3,W2
    ret

.global IntegerAddSubB_

IntegerAddSubB_:
    add X3,X0,X1
    sub X0,X3,X2
    ret
```

I tried compiling the assembly code into an object file first, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need to add a leading underscore to your symbols in the assembly file.

Answer (score 0):

As noted you have to add the leading "_" to the symbol names in you assembly file. This is just something your implementation of the C language does on ARM64 (on various combinations of architecture and OS).

One more reason why it's best to avoid assembly sources. The code can be much improved by using inline asm like this:

```
int IntegerAddSubA_(int a, int b, int c) {
    int r, t;
    asm("add %w[t], %w[a], %w[b]\n"
        "sub %w[r], %w[t], %w[c]"
        : [r] "=r" (r), [t] "=&r" (t)
        : [a] "%r" (a), [b] "r" (b), [c] "r" (c)
        : );
    return r;
}
```

Output operands: `r` is the final result and may overlap with the inputs. `t` gets written too and may not overlap any of the input registers.

Input operands: `a` is commutative with `b` (`a+b` == `b+a`) for all that matters on ARM64.

Clobber: Nothing is clobbered. Memory isn't altered.

Which compiles into this:

```
IntegerAddSubA_(int, int, int):                 // @IntegerAddSubA_(int, int, int)
        add     w8, w0, w1
        sub     w0, w8, w2
        ret
```

The big difference is that the compiler will inline this code and then pick registers that are available or already hold the values. It avoids having to shuffel registers around and do an expensive function call for simple things like a few asm instructions.

I recommend to only use assembly source files when you have complex functions.

```
int foo(int a1, int b1, int c1, int a2, int b2, int c2) {
    return IntegerAddSubA_(a1, b1, c1) + IntegerAddSubA_(a2, b2, c2);
}

foo(int, int, int, int, int, int):                           // @foo(int, int, int, int, int, int)
        add     w9, w0, w1
        sub     w8, w9, w2
        add     w10, w3, w4
        sub     w9, w10, w5
        add     w0, w9, w8
        ret
```

Notice how the 2 inlined versions of IntegerAddSubA_ use the registers the arguments are already in and use different temp and result registers leading to no opcode wasted.

Comment: *and every other arch clang supports I think* - Yes, x86-64 MacOS also prepends leading underscores to symbol names.  That convention is specific to the OS (or to MachO / MachO64 object files), not to the architecture.  Linux uses ELF object files, and does *not* prepend leading underscores (on any ISA), as you can see in the Godbolt output you copy/pasted in your last code block.

Comment: 32-bit x86 Windows does use leading underscores, but x64 Windows doesn't, so even within an OS, it can differ by architecture.  Compilers including clang know the convention for whatever ISA/OS combo they're targeting.

Comment: I had problems with this before and just have a macro that defines the symbol with and without `_`.

Comment: Also, for someone just learning asm, GNU C inline asm is the last thing I'd recommend.  You have to understand asm pretty well to be able to describe it *accurately* to the compiler using your constraints, and getting anything wrong (even a missing early-clobber, or writing an input operand) will silently break in mysterious ways depending on the surrounding C and optimization level.  Or worse, will happen to work so beginners don't realize they're getting it wrong.  If you want efficiency, don't use hand-written asm at all for simple addition in a C program!

Comment: The point of the exercise here is (I hope) to learn a bit of asm so they can read compiler output, or move on to actually useful things.  GNU C inline asm is a significant extra layer of complexity separate from actual asm, vs. learning a calling convention and the leading-underscore convention.  See also https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Comment: *don't use hand-written asm* is always a good recommendation. I would disagree with inline asm being the last thing to recommend. Thinking about what output, input and clobber to use teaches you about asm, makes you think twice about what you write. I would further recommend writing inline asm for single opcodes where possible. The above example should have inline asm for `add` and `sub` separately and just call the two. Getting a single opcode right isn't that hard. gcc and clang also provide a lot of __builtin_* functions for asm instructions in an architecture independent way, use them.

Comment: The "calling convention" part is actually why I prefer inline asm. I rather bother with the output, input, clobber stuff than the details of the calling convention.